# Application not a procedure error in Racket

Tags: racket

I'm trying to write a function called dates_in_month that takes a list of dates and a month and returns a list holding the dates from the argument list of dates that are in the month. The returned list should contain dates in the order they were originally given. However I'm new to Racket and I'm getting the error "application: not a procedure;
expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
given: 5"
Does anyone know what this means or how to fix it? If anyone can point out my error that'd be much appreciated.

This is the code i am working on with my test case at the bottom.

```lisp
#lang racket

(define (append lst1 lst2)
  (if (null? lst1)
      lst2
      (cons (car lst1) (append (cdr lst1) lst2))))

(define (dates_in_month dates month)
  (if (null? dates)
      '()
      (let ((date (car dates)))
        (if (= (month date) month)
            (cons date (dates_in_month (cdr dates) month))
            (dates_in_month (cdr dates) month)))))

(define test-dates '(#(1 1 2000) #(2 2 2000) #(3 3 2000) #(4 4 
2000) #(5 5 2000) #(6 6 2000)))
(dates_in_month test-dates 5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is caused by calling `(month date)`- `month` should be some procedure, which you want to call with the argument `date` (`date` will be some vector), but `month` has value `5`, that isn't a procedure.

That is the meaning of the error message:
*"application: not a procedure; expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments given: 5"*

I guess you need to get somehow the second element of the vector `date` and then compare it with the value of `month`. You should use the function [`vector-ref`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/vectors.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._vector-ref%29%29)- example:

```
> (vector-ref #(5 5 2000) 1)
5
```

See also [DrRacket docs for Vectors](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/vectors.html) for other functions for working with vectors.

And if you can, you could also use [`filter`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._filter%29%29) instead of recursion. Here are both variants:

```
(define (dates-in-month dates month)
  (if (null? dates)
      '()
      (let ((date (car dates)))
        (if (= (vector-ref date 1) month)
            (cons date (dates-in-month (cdr dates) month))
            (dates-in-month (cdr dates) month)))))

(define (dates-in-month2 dates month)
  (filter (lambda (date) (= (vector-ref date 1) month))
          dates))

(define test-dates '(#(1 1 2000) #(2 2 2000) #(3 3 2000) #(4 4 2000) #(5 5 2000) #(6 6 2000)))
(dates-in-month test-dates 5)
(dates-in-month2 test-dates 5)
```

And [`append`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._append%29%29) is already part of the DrRacket language, so you don't have to reimplement it.